# How to catch this exception in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using BeautifulSoup, how to guard against elements not being found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376666/using-beautifulsoup-how-to-guard-against-elements-not-being-found)

I have the following Python error when Using BeautifulSoup to find all options in a page:

```
   for item in soup.find(id="start_dateid").find_all('option'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

The problem is when the page do not have id="start_dateid", will generate an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

How to prevent this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your "subsoup" to a variable first:

```
thing = soup.find(id="start_dateid")
if thing:
    for option in thing.find_all('option'):
        # potato potato potato
```